# Concatenate Spark Dataframe N times

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with N lines in it and it has only one column. I want to copy it N times and concatenate. So at the end I want to create another dataframe with N^2 lines.

How can I achieve that simply using Scala? I do not want to use for loops etc. because N is large.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a fold function:

```
(0 until df.count.toInt).foldLeft(df){case (acc,_) => acc.unionAll(df)}.show
```

The only constraint is that N must be less than Int.Max_Value. Hope this helps :)

You can test with a small df:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(("r1"),("r2"),("r3"))).toDF("c")
```